# Python: How to extract multiple strings from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has a specific column containing strings in the format of:
Building = Building_A and Floor = Floor_4
Building = Building_D and Floor = Floor_2

I would like to extract only the building and floor names, concatenated into a single string / new column.
E.g. Building_A/Floor_4 
Building_D/Floor_2

I've spent about an hour looking through previous posts and was not able to find something to match what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some example data?

Comment: `str.extract` accepts regex arguments, so you can use multiple or statements (represented with a `|`) `df[col].str.extract('(floor\d+|building\w{1}')` or something like that

Answer (score 3):

Assume we have dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': ["Building = Building_A and Floor = Floor_4",\
                           "Building = Building_Z and Floor = Floor_9",\
                           "Building = Martello and Floor = Ground"]})
```

First define pattern to extract:

```
pat = "(Floor_\d+)|(Building_\w{1})"
```

Alternatively if You look for all words after `"= "`:

```
pat = r"(?<== )(\w+)"
```

Please note lookbehind `(?<=)` in pattern definition.

Then apply lambda function to column `txt`:

```
df['txt_extract'] = \
df[['txt']].apply(lambda r: "/".join(r.str.extractall(pat).stack()), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0    Building_A/Floor_4
1    Building_Z/Floor_9
2    Martello/Ground
```

Instead of `str.extract` use `str.extractall` which looks for all occurences of pattern. Resulting searches are stacked and joined with `"/"` separator. 
Please note that order of patterns found is preserved what may be important in Your case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however it looks like my sample data was not inclusive of all strings (they do not all have Building_ / Floor_ in the string). I guess the real requirement is to extract the string after each = , regardless of string format. 

Example: Building = Martello and Floor = Ground.

Comment: If the task requires another set of patterns, feel free to modify `pat` string accordingly. When Your input data is messy or contains multiple formats it can be hard to write regular expression pattern which covers all combinations.
Providing real data sample as @AMC asked would be very helpfull.

Comment: Alternatively if You look for all words after `"= "` use pattern `pat = r"(?<== )(\w+)"`. 
This should solve the problem. I've edited the answer.